# Reduce Output in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, output, visual-studio-2017

how can I reduce the output in the output window?

I am not interested about the output that is under "Hello world!".
How can I hide it?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5kCg.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The verbosity of content in the output tool window can be controlled in some cases. Eg. some settings in Tools | Options | Debugging | General.

However, while overly verbose much of the time, having the diagnostic information can also quickly help solve what would otherwise be hard to repeat problems. (And, IME, often show up issues before you'll see symptoms in the functionality of the debugging target.)

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that it didn't work.
I unchecked everything in Tools | Options | Debugging | General and it still appears.
https://imgur.com/a/6hqb3

Comment: Nobody knows how to do this?